Degree of divisors of projective algebraic varieties
Let $k$ be any commutative field, not necessarily algebraically closed. I have some question on the definition of the degree of divisor on algebraic varieties over $k$. Since the degree is a linear map, I will just be focusing on the degree of codimension 1 points.
Question 1 (Projective space, algebraically closed) First, the easiest case should be $X=\mathbb{P}_k^n$. If $k$ is algebraically closed, the degree of a subvariety $Y\subset X$ is defined in Hartshorne I.7. Moreover, if $Y$ has codimension 1, then since height 1 primes in UFD are principal, $Y=V((P))$ for some homogeneous irreducible polynomial $P\in k[T_0,...,T_n]$. My question is, do we have $deg(P)=deg(Y)$ ?
Question 2 (Projective space, not algebraically closed) I keep the same notation as in question 1 but now $k$ is no longer algebraically closed. How do I define $deg(Y)$ ? When $n=1$, the degree of a point $P$ is just the local degree $[k(P):k]$. But if $n>1$, the local degree $[k(x):k]$ at a generic point $x$ of $Y$ is not finite, right ?
Question 3 (General projective variety) Now, let $X$ be a projective variety with a morphism $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_k^n$. Let $x\in X$ be a codimension $1$ point and $Y=V(x)$. How do I define the degree of $x$ ? I am aware that this should depend on the embedding. Can I just see $Y$ as a subvariety of $\mathbb{P}^n_k$ (via $X\rightarrow \mathbb{P}_k^n$) and define $deg(x)$ as $deg(Y)$ where $deg(Y)$ is defined by questions 1 and 2 ?
Question 4 (Behavior with morphisms) Let $X,Y$ be two projective $k$-varieties with a morphism $f:X\rightarrow Y$ and suppose that $f$ has good enough properties (finite, dominant ?). I want to understand how the degree behaves with respect to $f$. First of all, since I am excepting that the answer to 3 depends on the embedding, can I make sure the "projectiveness" of $X$ and $Y$ are "compatible" so that it makes sense to compare the degrees ? Now, take a codimension 1 point $y\in Y$ and $x\in f^{-1}(y)$. With good assumptions on $f$, we should have $x$ of codimension $1$ in $X$. Can I relate $deg(x)$ and $deg(y)$. For example, is it true that $deg(f^*(y))=\sum_{x\in f^{-1}(y)} [k(x):k(y)]deg(x)$ ?
Thank you.

Q1 is Proposition I.7.6 (d) in Hartshorne.

For question 3, exercise II.6.2 in Hartshorne defines it that way. For question 4, in the case of curves, refer to proposition II.6.9 in Hartshorne. But I think it doesn't really answer your question 4, since the degree of a divisor of curve (formal sum of points) is intrinsic. I don't know much more, but I hope someone answers this!
